# docker exec error with sh command returns "Unterminated quoted string"

Tags: docker

If I run two commands:

```sh
export TMPCMD='sh -c "if [ `uname -m` = aarch64 ]; then echo 0; fi"'
docker exec container sh -c "..."
```

It produces an error:

```
[: 1: [: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

How might I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So far I have tried I could not find to execute like `docker exec container sh -c "..."`

Alternatively, You can create a shell script file name example `Stackoverflow.sh`

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY Stackoverflow.sh bin/Stackoverflow.sh
RUN chmod u+x bin/Stackoverflow.sh
RUN bin/Stackoverflow.sh
```

---

```
docker exec -it <conyainer-ID> bash
root@<conyainer-ID>:/bin# ./Stackoverflow.sh
#=>Logging-Container has started.
#=>Check uname -m command.
#=>0
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: @tangfangzhi - let me know if my question help.